# How to use std::replace_if to replace elements with its incremented value?

Tags: c++, string, lambda, replace

I am trying to write a std::replace_if function that takes in a string and replaces all the vowels with a consonant on its right.

How to capture the current iterating character from the string and replace it with its incremented value using a lambda within std::replace_if function

Example :

input : aeiou

output : bfjpv

Assume all characters to be lowercase

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::cin >> str;

    std::replace_if(
        str.begin(), str.end(), [&](char c)
        { return std::string("aeiou").find(c) != std::string::npos; },
        [&](char c)
        { return static_cast<char>(c + 1); });

    std::cout << str;
}
```

Comment: write a plain (range based) loop. `std::replace_if` takes a single `new_value`. Most standard algorithms can be made to do something the arent meant to do, but why would you?

Comment: If you want to do it via `replace_if`, then I think you need to loop over "aeiou" first and do 5 rounds of replace. Alternatively, you might simply search (via `find_if`) and replace.

Comment: i was just curious if it can be done just with replace if by pulling out the current character in each iteration

Comment: Notice that `a`-`z` is not guaranteed to be consecutive (as EBCDIC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::replace_if` cannot do what you want.  It accepts only a single new value.

To do what you want either use `std::for_each`:

```
std::for_each(
    str.begin(),
    str.end(),
    [](char& c) {
        if (std::string("aeiou").find(c) != std::string::npos) {
            c = c + 1;
        }
    }
);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/db3840817cb18796)

Or use a normal loop:

```
for (char& c : str) {
    if (std::string("aeiou").find(c) != std::string::npos) {
        c = c + 1;
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e9835c629f3c88a4)